# Render tooltop element on specific Ref

Tags: reactjs, tooltip

I want to render my `TooltipComponent` on a button only when the user click on this button and specific condition holds.

I'm familiar with the `react-tooltip` library, but I don't want to use it, my opinion is not positive about this lib. In this library there is a `ReactTooltop.show` function.

I want to be able to do something like (again, without using this lib:

```
const onBtnClick = () => {
    if(...condition...){
       MyTooltip.show(btnRef, ...); // maybe pass some arguments like tooltip text...
    }
}
```

Any idea how can i implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a `popover`, [here is an example](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/). You can find some on the internet but it's also easy to recreate :

.ts:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [isPopoverVisible, setPopoverVisibility] = React.useState(false);
  const togglePopover = () => {
    if (!isPopoverVisible) {
      setPopoverVisibility(!isPopoverVisible);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => setPopoverVisibility(!isPopoverVisible), 20000);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
        Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
        Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
        Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
        Content Content Content Content
      </div>
      <span>Some content</span>
      <Popover
        isVisible={isPopoverVisible}
        resetVisibility={togglePopover}
      >
        <button onClick={() => togglePopover()}>coucou</button>
      </Popover>
      <div>other content</div>
    </>
  );
};

const Popover = ({ children, isVisible, resetVisibility, position }) => {
  const [classes, setClasses] = React.useState("popover");
  const [style, setStyle] = React.useState({});
  const childrenRef = React.createRef();
  const popoverMessageRef = React.createRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const messagePos = popoverMessageRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const childrenPos = childrenRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();

    // x and y from getBoundingClientRect() dos not take into account the padding, we need to add it to our calculs
    const messagePaddingFull = window
      .getComputedStyle(popoverMessageRef.current)
      .getPropertyValue("padding");
    const messagePadding = 
      messagePaddingFull.substring(0, messagePaddingFull.length - 2);

  if(position){
     if (position.toLowerCase() === "top") {
      setStyle({
        top: `${childrenPos.y - messagePos.height - 10}px`,
        left: `${(childrenPos.x - messagePadding) - childrenPos.width / 2}px`
      });
    } else if(position.toLowerCase() === "left"){
      setStyle({
        top: `${(+childrenPos.y + +messagePadding/2) - childrenPos.height / 2}px`,
        left: `${(childrenPos.x) - messagePos.width - 10}px`
      });
    } else if(position.toLowerCase() === "right"){
      setStyle({
        top: `${(+childrenPos.y + +messagePadding/2) - childrenPos.height / 2}px`,
        left: `${+childrenPos.x + +childrenPos.width + 10}px`
      });
    } else {
      // default bottom
      setStyle({
        top: `${(childrenPos.y) + childrenPos.height + 10}px`,
        left: `${(childrenPos.x  - messagePadding/2) - childrenPos.width / 2}px`
      });
    }
  } else {
      // default bottom position
      setStyle({
        top: `${(childrenPos.y) + childrenPos.height + 10}px`,
        left: `${(childrenPos.x - messagePadding/2) - childrenPos.width / 2}px`
      });
    }

    console.log("messagePos = ", messagePos);
    console.log("messagePos = ", messagePadding);
    console.log("childrenPos = ", childrenPos);
  }, [classes]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setClasses(`popover ${isVisible ? "pop" : ""}`);

    if (isVisible) {
      resetVisibility();
    }
  }, [isVisible]);

  return (
    <div className="popover-component">
      <span ref={childrenRef}>{children}</span>
      <div className={classes} ref={popoverMessageRef} style={style}>
        This is the popover
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

.css:

```
.popover-component{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.popover{
  display: none;
  position: fixed; /* You can play with absolute position as well */
  background-color: #797979;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.pop {
  display: block; /* You can play with inline-block as well */
}
```

[Here is the repro on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xv7vaj?file=style.css). You can then adjust the  popover by getting the children's width and playing with it (like recreating the options "top", "bottom", "left", "right" by changing your algo).

Comment: I want to create a generic component so I can use my tooltip easily everywhere in the app. Also, How can I show the tooltip for X seconds and that disappear?

Comment: Well then my repro is what you want i think. I edited my popover component to show the tooltip for 2 seconds. It uses a `useEffect` that depends on `isVisible`. When  `isVisible` changes, the useEffect show the popover and wait for 2 seconds before to hide it again.

Comment: I found that the best approach is to use redux-saga, react-redux as I used for showing modals

Comment: redux shouldn't be involved in this kind of thing. The best approeach would be to use an existing component

Comment: Why not? why it can be involved in showing modal but now showing tooltip? With redux-saga i can easily implement the hiding after X seconds.

Comment: I updated the code to make it works properly is you're curious. Just added a reset that is triggered when `isVisible` is true.

Comment: Well i don't know about redux-saga, but to me a popover feature should be independant, except for the condition that display it or not of course, but it's a personal opinion

Comment: I understand what you are saying. My only problem now, is how to calculate popup position, given a ref to the element i want to put the tooltip on.

Comment: I added some code (here and on the repro) to show you how to position your message. Maybe there's a better solution to calculate the position, i'm not good at maths haha :p Hope it helps.